# Collections.max with custom Comparator on list

Tags: java, collections, interface

I have an array list of Location objects that I want to find the max and min value of. However, when calling collections.max(listN, PopulationComparator) it gives me the minimum value whereas for collection.min() it returns the max value. The problem is resolved once changing the order to be descending, but I don't understand why this would even matter.

```
static class PopulationComparator implements Comparator <Location>{
    public int compare(Location a, Location b){ 

      // ascending order
        if(a.getPop() > b.getPop()){ 
            return 1;
        }else if(a.getPop() < b.getPop()){
            return -1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args){
Location maxPopulation = Collections.max(listN, new PopulationComparator());
}
```

Comment: What exactly does `getPop` return?

Comment: Your code looks correct (though it could be simplified). Provide a complete example, demonstration.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce (`ideone.com` )](https://ideone.com/yujWST).

Comment: How you know which value is being returned? `maxArea` suggest you want it sorted by area; `getPop()` suggest it is sorted by population; I am assuming a lot, better include a [mre] including test data in the question. What is meant by "*changing the order ... why this would even matter*"??

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “changing the order to be descending”?

Comment: I assumed getPop() is the method that returns the population attribute of the Area.